# Post em destaque - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, layout

Então, quero fazer algo como no exemplo a seguir http://www.f1bc.com/

Tipo, o quadro que aparece na home do site que deixei, onde tem um post com a imagem grande e 2 do lado direito.

Queria fazer exatamente isso, deixar um post em destaque e os outros 2 menores, como faço pra passar os argumentos e puxar o post de forma que um deles fique em destaque?

O ideal seria tb eu conseguir criar um campo no post type que desce pra escolher se ficaria em destaque ou não, tenho o CMB2 instalado, mas ainda não consegui usa-lo...

Obs: Sim, sou iniciante...

Answer (score 0):

Para deixar os posts ou páginas em destaque na home page, entre na página de edição e marque a estrela. Não precisa de nenhum plugin ou campo especial.
Nesta mesma página você determina a ordem dos artigos/posts.

Sugiro que para ordenar, use numeros espaçados, isto é, em vez de 1,2,3,... use 10,20,30,...

Desta maneira se precisar mudar a ordem dos destaques será mais fácil.

Finalmente, para que apareça como na página mencionada (imagem grande à esquerda, com duas menores a direita) será preciso mexer no tema do site, ou pelo menos, no CSS.